# What is the best way to handle incoming SMS messages?

Tags: sms, messaging

I have a client who wants a solution to allow delivery people to text (SMS messaging)  in that they have completed a pick up at a particular location. What I'm looking for is Code to read an imbound SMS message or a SMS component if appropiate. This would allow me to create a windows service to read the message and update a SQL record accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably not quite what you're looking for but one approach is to use a gateway like [iTagg](http://www.itagg.com) which provides a number of interfaces for developers to send and receive SMS/MMS etc. Depending on your location, iTagg may be no use but I'm sure there'll be an equivalent for your region.

Answer (score 2):

Sometime ago I implemented something similar using a GSM modem. I think most of the GSM modems offer AT commands that can be used for receiving and sending SMS messages. At the time, I used a library in Java that provided a easy to use API. The commands to read and send SMS are really easy but I bet there is something in .Net for that purpose that can make the task even easier.

I made a little search and I found this [article](http://twit88.com/blog/2007/09/22/use-the-net-sms-library-to-retrieve-phone-settings/) with an example of using AT commands to interact with a GSM phone. I looked into the supplied source and it includes a library with operations related to SMS.

In my previous project I used a Siemens GSM modem with a RS232 interface. It wasn't very expensive and was able to manage all the messages sent by onboard units placed in vehicles. But if you have a unused phone it can work as well.

Comment: Thanks I'll have a look. Its the kind of solution I need to implement as my app needs to be able to handle received messages and not send any messages.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Luke, I am thinking more of a GSM modem which would be connected to the server. I think this would give more control rather than go through a third party, but I take your point and will investigate further.