# International SMS Forwarding

Tags: sms

Is it possible to get all the SMS forwarded to a mobile number? Is there any web service  provider you know of?

Comment: Yes. I am trying to build an online application that will be able to receive any SMS from anywhere. Thanks.

Comment: What do  you mean "any SMS" You can only get SMS sent to a number you own.

Comment: You'll probably need to add some more information before this question can be answered, mate...

Comment: By "any SMS", I meant SMS from any country. Sorry for the confusion, mate. :-) I am using Java/JSP to build an e-commerce site where you can reserve certain items through a text. So I need a web service who will receive those SMS and I can retrieve 'em through their web service. Thanks.

Comment: Yo you need to send sms? You need people to send sms to a number and then you receive them via internet to your software?

Comment: "You need people to send sms to a number and then you receive them via internet to your software?

-- Yes. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

Some (near) duplicates:

1. [SMS API Suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804924/sms-api-suggestions)
2. [How do I design sms service ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576940/how-do-i-design-sms-service)
3. [Receive SMS messages by web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526046/receive-sms-messages-by-web-application)
4. [Free SMS API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238579/free-sms-api)
5. [What is the best way to handle incoming SMS messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115361/what-is-the-best-way-to-handle-incoming-sms-messages)

plus others, if you search for SMS and incoming or receiving.